# How does property mappings work in Content Search Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, display-template, cswp

I am using the Content Search Web Part to display some drone photos.  In the shot below, it is showing each building with the File Name and the date/time of the photograph beneath it.  I would like to replace the File Name with Building Number.

I have a column in my Drone Photo Picture Library called Building Number.  I have mapped a managed property to the crawled property and confirmed it is being returned in the search results by using the SharePoint Search Query Tool.

The issue is when I click the Line 1 dropdown in property mappings, the managed property building number is not appearing in the list.  Does this happen automatically, or must I go into the Display Template of the the Content Search Web Part?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: This may be only a workaround, but couldn't you just set the Title to the building number? The Title is only set to the filename because there was no title set on the file.

Answer (score 1):

So the way to add Managed Properties to the drop downs in the Content Search Web part, is to change the Item display template by adding the following to the ManagedPropertyMapping tag at the top of the template:

```
'property Name'{property display name}:'managed property'
```

Where **property Name** is the name used in javascript to refer to the managed property.
**{property display name}** is the name that appears in the UI (the dropdown in the Content Search webpart
**managed property** is the property you mapped to the crawled property